# how to run AsyncTask when Activity Start

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As the title suggest, I have a heavy process such as getting data from web service, setting adapter for listview , and many more like initializing button and image.

so I am creating AsyncTask that will run my `HttpGet` method, and then set the listview adapter.

but when i call the `AsyncTask` in oncreate I get following error

```
can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()
```

how can I run the `Asynctask` when activity start but not to put the code in `oncreate`?

my code :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    URLService = getString(R.string.URLService);
    Enc_Pass = getString(R.string.password_encryption);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    strUserId = pref.getString("userId", null);
    strPassword = pref.getString("Password", null);
    code_comp = pref.getString("CompanyCode",null);



    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProfile);
    new LoadDataForActivity().execute();

    imageToUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}

 private class LoadDataForActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        getAll();
        getTotalLeaveBalance();
        getMedicalBalance();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

  private void getAll()
{
    try {
        String Status = "";
        String valueEncrypt = strUserId + "|" + strPassword;
        String encc  = "";
        try {
            encc = ANGGACRYYPT.encrypt(Enc_Pass,valueEncrypt);
            encc = encc.replace("+", "%2B");
        }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
            //handle error
        }
        RESTClient client = new RESTClient(URLService+"do?method=dologin&value=" +encc );

        client.Execute(RESTClient.RequestMethod.GET);
        String response = client.getResponse();

        response = response.replace("\\\"", "\"");
        response = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(response);
        Status = jsonObject.get("Status").toString();
        if (Status == "true") {
            String dataku = jsonObject.get("Data").toString();

            try {
                dataku = ANGGACRYYPT.decrypt(Enc_Pass, dataku);
            }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
                //handle error - could be due to incorrect password or tampered encryptedMsg
            }

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject structure = (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataku);

            etFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullname);
            etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
            etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
            etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
            etDirectSuperiorName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDirectSuperiorName);
            etSisaCuti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSisaCuti);
            etFullName.setText(structure.get("Fullname") == null ? "" : structure.get("Fullname").toString());
            etEmail.setText(structure.get("Email") == null ? "" : structure.get("Email").toString());
            etPhone.setText(structure.get("Phone") == null ? "" : structure.get("Phone").toString());
            etAddress.setText(structure.get("Address") == null ? "" : structure.get("Address").toString());
            etDirectSuperiorName.setText(structure.get("DirectSuperiorName") == null ? "" : structure.get("DirectSuperiorName").toString());
            //  etSisaCuti.setText(structure.get("LeaveBalance") == null ? "" : structure.get("LeaveBalance").toString());
            strPhoto = structure.get("strPhoto") == null ? "" : structure.get("strPhoto").toString();

            imageToUpload = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strPhoto, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            //show the image
            imageToUpload.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            lv.setAdapter(new ListProfileAdapter(this,mItems));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Data Failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getMedicalBalance(){
    try{
        String valueEncrypt = strUserId  + "|" + code_comp;
        String encc  = "";
        try {
            encc = ANGGACRYYPT.encrypt(Enc_Pass,valueEncrypt);
            encc = encc.replace("+", "%2B");
        }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
            //handle error
        }
       /* RESTClient client = new RESTClient(URLService+"get?method=getmedicalapprovallist&value="
                + userId + URLEncoder.encode("|", "UTF-8") + rowsPerPage);*/

        RESTClient client = new RESTClient(URLService+"get?method=getkuotaclaimbyemployeename&value="
                + encc);

        client.Execute(RESTClient.RequestMethod.GET);
        String response = client.getResponse();

        response = response.replace("\\\"", "\"");
        response = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(response);
        mItems = new ArrayList<ListProfileItem>();

        String Status = jsonObject.get("Status").toString();
        if (Status == "true") {
            // JSONArray structure = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("DataList");
            String dataku = jsonObject.get("DataList").toString();

            try {
                dataku = ANGGACRYYPT.decrypt(Enc_Pass, dataku);
            }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
                //handle error - could be due to incorrect password or tampered encryptedMsg
            }

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray structure = (JSONArray) parser.parse(dataku);
            for (int i = 0; i < structure.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) structure.get(i);

                item = new ListProfileItem();

                item.claimpostname = data.get("claim_post_name").toString();


                String claimamount = data.get("max_limit_per_year").toString();
                if (claimamount!=("0.0"))
                {
                    Double amount = Double.parseDouble(claimamount);
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
                    String AmountFormatted = formatter.format(amount);
                    item.claimpostamount = AmountFormatted;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.claimpostamount = data.get("max_limit_per_year").toString();
                }
                mItems.add(item);
            }
            // initialize and set the list adapter
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

private void getTotalLeaveBalance()
{
   try {
        String valueEncrypt = code_comp + "|" + strUserId;
        String encc  = "";
        try {
            encc = ANGGACRYYPT.encrypt(Enc_Pass,valueEncrypt);
            encc = encc.replace("+", "%2B");
        }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
            //handle error
        }
        RESTClient client = new RESTClient(URLService+"get?method=gettotalleavebalance&value=" +encc );
        client.Execute(RESTClient.RequestMethod.GET);
        String response = client.getResponse();

        response = response.replace("\\\"", "\"");
        response = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(response);
        String Status = jsonObject.get("Status").toString();
        if (Status == "true") {
            String dataku = jsonObject.get("Data").toString();

            try {
                dataku = ANGGACRYYPT.decrypt(Enc_Pass, dataku);
            }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
                //handle error - could be due to incorrect password or tampered encryptedMsg
            }

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject structure = (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataku);
            etSisaCuti.setText(structure.get("total_leave_balance") == null ? "" : structure.get("total_leave_balance").toString());

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Data Failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

note that in my get() method there is a httpget that can be a slow process depending the connection, so i need this all get method to be inside asynctask so they'll not make the process slow

and what should i return in DoInBackground() ?

**---UPDATED----**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    URLService = getString(R.string.URLService);
    Enc_Pass = getString(R.string.password_encryption);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    strUserId = pref.getString("userId", null);
    strPassword = pref.getString("Password", null);
    code_comp = pref.getString("CompanyCode",null);
    etFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullname);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    etDirectSuperiorName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDirectSuperiorName);
    etSisaCuti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSisaCuti);
    imageToUpload = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);


    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProfile);
    new LoadDataForActivity().execute();


    imageToUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}

 private class LoadDataForActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setClickable(false);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        getAll();
        getTotalLeaveBalance();
        getMedicalBalance();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    }

}

private void getAll()
{
    try {
        String Status = "";
        String valueEncrypt = strUserId + "|" + strPassword;
        String encc  = "";
        try {
            encc = ANGGACRYYPT.encrypt(Enc_Pass,valueEncrypt);
            encc = encc.replace("+", "%2B");
        }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
            //handle error
        }
       RESTClient client = new RESTClient(URLService+"do?method=dologin&value=" +encc );

        client.Execute(RESTClient.RequestMethod.GET);
        String response = client.getResponse();

        response = response.replace("\\\"", "\"");
        response = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(response);
        Status = jsonObject.get("Status").toString();
        if (Status == "true") {
            String dataku = jsonObject.get("Data").toString();

            try {
                dataku = ANGGACRYYPT.decrypt(Enc_Pass, dataku);
            }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
                //handle error - could be due to incorrect password or tampered encryptedMsg
            }

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject structure = (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataku);


            etFullName.setText(structure.get("Fullname") == null ? "" : structure.get("Fullname").toString());
            etEmail.setText(structure.get("Email") == null ? "" : structure.get("Email").toString());
            etPhone.setText(structure.get("Phone") == null ? "" : structure.get("Phone").toString());
            etAddress.setText(structure.get("Address") == null ? "" : structure.get("Address").toString());
            etDirectSuperiorName.setText(structure.get("DirectSuperiorName") == null ? "" : structure.get("DirectSuperiorName").toString());
            //  etSisaCuti.setText(structure.get("LeaveBalance") == null ? "" : structure.get("LeaveBalance").toString());
            strPhoto = structure.get("strPhoto") == null ? "" : structure.get("strPhoto").toString();

            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strPhoto, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            //show the image
            imageToUpload.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            lv.setAdapter(new ListProfileAdapter(this,mItems));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Data Failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code for getAll(); 
        getTotalLeaveBalance(); 
        getMedicalBalance();

Comment: ive update my code, pls check

Comment: Updating the UI elements can not be done inside the background thread. ie, You can not write `EditText.setText()` inside `doInBackground()`. UI updation should be done inside the `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask<>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize and update Views inside doInBackground() , Because of that you are getting error "cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()".

To avoid above error you should initialize below code in onCreate

```
etFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullname);
            etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
            etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
            etAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
            etDirectSuperiorName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDirectSuperiorName);
            etSisaCuti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSisaCuti);
```

imageToUpload = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);

After that initialize global element in which your json contains for updating text and setting bitmap.

```
JSONObject mStructure;  // declare it at global
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 mStructure= (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataku);
```

After that on your onPostExecute() you can update views like below

```
 etFullName.setText(structure.get("Fullname") == null ? "" : structure.get("Fullname").toString());
            etEmail.setText(structure.get("Email") == null ? "" : structure.get("Email").toString());
            etPhone.setText(structure.get("Phone") == null ? "" : structure.get("Phone").toString());
            etAddress.setText(structure.get("Address") == null ? "" : structure.get("Address").toString());
            etDirectSuperiorName.setText(structure.get("DirectSuperiorName") == null ? "" : structure.get("DirectSuperiorName").toString());
            //  etSisaCuti.setText(structure.get("LeaveBalance") == null ? "" : structure.get("LeaveBalance").toString());
            strPhoto = structure.get("strPhoto") == null ? "" : structure.get("strPhoto").toString();

            imageToUpload = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strPhoto, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            //show the image
            imageToUpload.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

If anything i miss here you should do like these as I mention above and also read about [asyntask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Hope these help you.

Comment: hi thanks for answer,
but should i put the json parser in doInBackground or in preExeccute or onCreate?

i still got error , when i get from json and set it to the EditText. how can i past the process from doinBackground to the post execute ? 

i update my code above.

Comment: parse it on doInBackground() and initialize it to global variable.

Comment: ya, but how to parse my Get Process from doInBackground to someplace and initialize it ?

Comment: after initializing you can get these value in onPostExceute() as we mention json globally.

Comment: hi, im sorry, but i still dont get it, can you show me the sample code? bcs i declare my JSON Parser and structure inside GetAll(), and GetAll() are inside DoInBackground. so i dont know how to pass the process from doInBackground to OnPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getall()` in the `doInBackground()` and in the `getall()` you are accessing ui elements (EditTexts) you cannot do that ui elements can only be accessed from a ui thread. You can do that in the constructor or in `onPreExecute()` or in `onProgressUpdate(Progress... values)` or in `onPostExecute(Result result)` please see [This link for more details about `AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)